# Regular Expressions in C# Unity

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

I have strings in the form of: "t1 v2". and I need the numbers after the t and the v, seems pretty straight forward, im doing:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("t([0-9])");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(options);
if (matches.Count > 0) {
    foreach (Match match in matches) {
        CaptureCollection captures = match.Captures;
        Debug.Log(captures[0].Value);
    }
}
```

I've tried a few other things but it always returns "t1" I need it to return "1".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Also you miss digit near 'v'. Try this:
[`[tv]\K\d`](https://regex101.com/r/fL5CH7/1)
Outputs result as full match wihout grouping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything, you just need to pick right capture from result:

```
        var options = "t1 v2";

        var result = Regex.Matches(options, "[a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", result));//1;2
```

Or more straight forward

```
        result = Regex.Matches(options, "[a-zA-Z](?<foo>[0-9]+)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture).Cast<Match>().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Groups["foo"].Value)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", result));//1;2
```

And in your Regex query (important to mention, your query will miss 't32' and so on strings):

```
        result = Regex.Matches(options, "t([0-9])").Cast<Match>().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", result));//1
```