# C# Unity: Get public classes in script attached to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

edit: Vanethrane brought my attention to the fact that I am already calling classes in my examples - but I'm looking for those who's name I cannot check manually (it is for this purpose unknown).

Still new to reflections: I'm currently reading a bunch of properties and printing them - I'm eliminating the undesired ones by giving the ones I want a name with specific prefix. For example:

```
var elementProperties = new object();

if(element.GetComponent<MyFirstScript>() != null)
    elementProperties = element.GetComponent<MyFirstScript>();
else if(element.GetComponent<MySecondScript>() != null)
    elementProperties = element.GetComponent<MySecondScript>();
else
        return;

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = elementProperties.GetType().GetProperties();

for(int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
{
    if(properties[i].Name.Substring(0, 3) != "my_")
        continue;
    //IF VARIABLE NAME STARTS WITH "my_" DO STUFF WITH properties[i].PropertyType OR GetValue ...
}
```

The trouble is this doesn't automatically find classes. I thought it would better fit my needs if I would instead of searching by variable name, to make a class with extra variables such as bool isReadable = true; and some other neat information (isEditable, displayName etc.).

So, how do I go about it in this context?

Searching in entire GameObject as opposed to single scripts would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

For just getting a list of **all** components that are attached to a GameObject you can simply use ([Source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-all-components-in-a-gameobject.33575/))

```
GetComponents(typeof(Component));
```

Than for checking the components types / type names you might prefere using [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46750126/7111561) to look for certain matches without hai´ving to check the complete name.

In general it is recommend to use a [`switch - case`](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/switch-statements) instead of `if - else` if you are checking just one variable for different values since this is way more efficient.

Unfortunately this does not work for comparing types like

```
var Type = component.GetType();

// can not use switch for that
if(Type == typeof(MyFirstClass)) // ... etc
```

But you can use the Regex to match a certain part of the Type name using e.g.

```
var components = GetComponents(typeof(Component));

foreach(var component in components)
{
    var Type = component.GetType();
    var TypeName = Type.Name;

    // Matching types starting with My
    if( Regex.IsMatch(TypeName, "My.*"))
    {
       // ....
    }
}
```

(For writing and testing regex I recommend https://regexr.com)

Or you can use a `switch - case` for matching complete type names like

```
foreach(var component in components)
{
    var Type = component.GetType();
    var TypeName = Type.Name;

    switch(TypeName)
    {
        case "MyFirstClass":
        // ...
        break;

        case "MySecondClass":
        // ....
        break;

        //.... etc

        default:
        // Nothing matched
        return;
    }
}
```

Unlike an `if - else if - else` statement, a `swith - case` does not lose performance with more cases so even if there are a lot of names to check this might be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

you already have the script object why not just change its properties directly?

```
  MyFirstScript elementproperties = GameObject.GetComponent<MyFirstScript>();

script.my_blah="blahblah";
```

or in your case:

```
elementproperties.variable=change;
```

you need to add the public modifier to any variables you want to get from outside class

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify - these ("MyFirstScript", "MySecondScript") are familiar names - the classes I want to work with are located within these (which I assume is less relevant) - but more importantly I can't iterate with if, else if for their specific names because there are too many. I suppose - how would I get their list in the first place without manually checking if they are there?

Comment: Additionally, `var elementProperties = new object();` is dumb. Should just declare an explicit typed variable `MonoBehaviour elementProperties;` (Would be best to create an interface type that both scripts inherit from as well).